# How to add a new directive to an element from a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that I want to add other directives in its place. I am able to add the new directive's attribute but it does not seem to compile and do anything.

hat I have so far is: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DwGb1jn23fu08spW2hM9)

```
app.directive('xxx', function($compile) {
    return {
        priority: '3',
        compile: function(e, a) {
            e.removeAttr('xxx');
            a.$set('yyy','');
            return function(scope, el, attrs) {
                el.html('step 1');
                $compile(el)(scope);
            };
        }
    };
});

app.directive('yyy', function() {
    return {
        priority: '1',
        compile: function(e, a) {
            return function(scope, el, attrs) {
                el.html('step 2');
            };
        }
    };
});

app.directive('zzz', function() {
    return {
        priority: '2',
        compile: function(e, a) {
            return function(scope, el, attrs) {
                console.log('zzz');
            };
        }
    };
});
```

the html is

```
<div xxx zzz></div>
```

the current output is:

```
<div zzz yyy>Step 2</div>
```

which is what I want except that directive zzz is run twice!! and that is not good.

if I do not $compile in directive xxx after I add directive yyy, yyy does not execute and the result is

```
<div zzz>Step 1</div>
```

if I do not first remove xxx before $compile then the app crashes due to what I assume is infinitely trying to compile the xxx directive.

The priorities of the directives don't seem to have any effect.

What I need is to be able to add one or more directives from inside a directive *without* recompiling other directives on that element.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't remove the initial zzz directive from the element and instead add it in the xxx directive with `a.$set('zzz','');` like you're doing with yyy? Then it will only get compiled once.

Comment: @jbll I want xxx to be able to work with any other directive that happens to be on it. In this simple case it hardly matters that zzz is compiled twice but if zzz manipulated the DOM, then that would also happen twice.

Comment: Oh I see. I misunderstood your original question.